# GKE Node Upgrade "Out of Resources"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I had left my GKE cluster running 3 minor versions behind the latest and decided to finally upgrade. The master upgrade went well but then my node upgrades kept failing. I used the Cloud Shell console to manually start an upgrade and view the output, which said something along the lines of "`Zone X is out of resources, try Y instead.`" Unfortunately,I can't just spin up a new node pool in a new zone and have my pipeline work because I am using GitLab's AutoDevOps pipeline and they make certain assumptions about node pool naming and such that I can't find any way to override. I also don't want to potentially lose the data stored in my persistent volumes if I end up needing to re-create everything in a new node-pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this issue but couldn't find any questions posed on this particular problem, so I wanted to post the answer here in case someone else comes looking for it.

My particular problem was that I had a non-autoscaling node pool with a single node. For my purposes, that's enough for the application stack to run smoothly and I don't want to incur unforeseen charges with additional nodes automatically being added to the pool. However, this meant that the upgrade had to apparently share resources with everything else running on that node to perform the upgrade, which it didn't have enough of. The solution was simple: add more nodes temporarily.

Because this is specifically GKE, I was able to use a beta feature called "surge upgrade", which allows you to set the maximum number of "surge" nodes to add when performing an upgrade. Once this was enabled, I started the upgrade process again and it temporarily added an extra node, performed the upgrade, and then scaled back down to a single node.

If you aren't on GKE, or don't wish to use a beta feature (or can't), then simply resize the node pool with the node(s) that needs upgrading. I would add a single node unless you are positive you need more.